# Unload the Userform from second macro

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, userform

In my first macro, I show a UserForm `Cemealistfinal`. After using it, I hide the Userform to preserve the input information.

I  my second macro, I don't really need the information in the Userform so I use the following code to `Unload` the already hidden Userform.

```
Dim UForm As Object
For Each UForm In VBA.UserForms 
    If UForm.Visible = True Then
        UForm.Unload
    End If
Next
```

This doesn't work. I am not sure how to correctly unload the form from the second macro, is there another way to do it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by using another method, if that code already works?

Comment: @Wolfie actually its not working.

Comment: Why are you looping through all the user forms and not just using `Unload Cemealistfinal`?

Comment: @Wolfie because sometime I need previous information & Sometime I need blank userform. anyother Question? . `Unload` is only work in Form's  (Cemealistfinal) code, I need to `unload` from modules (Newmacros).

Comment: Did you create this form in the workbook, or do you create it from scratch within your module? i.e. does it exist in the "Forms" section of the VBA editor?

Comment: @Wolfie userform **Cemeafinallist** exit in Forms section. I need to `unload` it from Module section of VBA.

Comment: Right, you should just be able to use `Unload Cemeafinallist` from any module.

Comment: @Wolfie thanks anyway. problem was that I was using `unload me` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using code within a UserForm, you can use the `Me` object to refer to that UserForm

```
Unload Me
```

However, when in a sub within a separate module, you can simply refer to any UserForm by its name

```
' General
Unload UserForm1
' Your case
Unload Cemealistfinal
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will unload any and all userforms that are visible. You can get better control over what you are doing by use of variables to store references to your userforms.  For example:

If you set a public variable (a variable declared in a module, outside of any procedure) to store a reference to your userform, then you can reference it later:

```
Public oForm As UserForm1    'Public declaration of form
```

Now when you load the form, create the reference:

```
Public Sub LoadTheUserForm()
Set oForm = UserForm1
oForm.Show
End Sub
```

If you later want to close it, you can close it from a macro that references it directly:

```
Public Sub CloseUserForm()
If Not (oForm Is Nothing) Then
    Unload oForm
    Set oForm = Nothing
End If
End Sub
```

The `if` statement checks to see whether the public variable that you used for the form is in-use, and if so, it means the form is in-use.  It unloads it, and clears the reference (`Set oForm = Nothing`).  If you only want to close it if it is visible (or invisible), you can add another `If` statement.

```
Public Sub CloseInvisibleUserForm()
If Not (oForm Is Nothing) Then
    if oForm.Visible=false then
        Unload oForm
        Set oForm = Nothing
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're over-complicating this. You don't need the public variable, as UserForms are public anyway, you can just use `Unload UserForm1`?

Comment: I'm trying to show him a better way of doing something.  Yes, he can use `Unload UserForm1`, but unless UserForm1 was declared public, then it won't be in-scope in whatever macro he's running, because (as per the question title), he wants to unload it via a **second** macro.

Comment: But you can access user forms by name from any macro within the same workbook, they are public objects without being assigned to variables, assuming this is a "Forms" object within the workbook and not dynamically created within the first macro.

Comment: @ainwood appreciate your work. but `Unload UserForm` is much better :). It also works fine, if hide `UserForm` exit or not.